# Booting Google Chrome causes error message "There is no disk in the drive [...]"

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, drive-letter

Without any reason I suddenly receive an error message when booting *Google Chrome*:

> "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \
>   Device \ Harddisk3 \ ​​DR7"

(I don't know if it's translated it right, I received the message in German):

> "es befindet sich kein Datenträger im Laufwerk. Legen Sie einen Datenträger in Laufwerk \Device\Harddisk3\DR7 ein")

It seems like I need to change a drive letter, but I actually don't know which letter and if I'm headed in the right direction.

These are my drives:

- `C:\` for installation stuff
- `D:\` for data
- `E:\` is the  DVD-drive
- `J:\` is the BD-ROM-drive

I actually never changed these drive letters. My operating system is *Windows 7*. Re-installing *Google Chrome* didn't help.

How do I solve this problem? What's the issue?

Comment: windows boots fine ?

Comment: yes, windows boots fine. Without any problems. Rebooting Windows also doesn't help.

Comment: custom chrome builds are usually not very stable , you could try a fresh install

Comment: wow, seems like this was easier than I expected. 
I already deinstalled and installed it again, but it seems like I installed with an older installation which caused the problem. Now I took the installation from the original page and right now I don't have any problems anymore. Thanks for the hint. *facepalm to myself*

Comment: Please don't edit "solved" into your title. Post the solution as an answer (when you can) and then accept it.

Comment: thanks for notifying. 
The solution of my problem was that I deinstalled and installed Google Chrome again. But not with the old installation file. I used the newest original installation file from the chrome homepage.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution of my problem was that I uninstalled and reinstalled Google Chrome from the newest original installation file from the Chrome homepage